# Python dice rolling simulation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble with a code where I need to roll a six-sided die 1000 times and then return a list of how many times each number on the die was rolled.

The code runs just fine and I can get a list at the end, but my list keeps having 0 in place of four so it appears that my function is not keeping tabs on the number 4 being rolled or it's not being rolled at all.

I'm kind of stumped and I thought maybe someone here could help. Any and all help is appreciated.

Here's my code.

```
def rollDie(number):
    one = 0
    two = 0
    three = 0
    four = 0
    five = 0
    six = 0
    for i in range(0, number):
        roll=int(random.randint(1,6))
        if roll == 1:
            one = one+1
        elif roll == 2:
            two = two+1
        elif roll == 3:
            three = three+1
        elif roll == 4:
            four == four+1
        elif roll == 5:
            five = five+1
        elif roll == 6:
            six = six+1
    return [one,two,three,four,five,six]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a small typo; you are testing for equality, not assigning:

```
four == four+1
```

should be:

```
four = four+1
```

However, you already have a number between 1 and 6, why not make that into an index into the results list? That way you don't have to use so many `if` statements. Keep your data out of your variable names:

```
def rollDie(number):
    counts = [0] * 6
    for i in range(number):
        roll = random.randint(1,6)
        counts[roll - 1] += 1
    return counts
```

Comment: Well and now I feel stupid for making such a dumb mistake. Thanks for being my spellcheck though I appreciate your time.

Comment: Errr... @MartijnPieters is always faster than everyone for rewriting this kind of algorithm, damn :p

Answer (score 0):

I can't improve on Martijn Pieters's answer.  :-)  But this problem can be more conveniently solved using a list.

```
import random

def rollDie(number):
    # create a list with 7 values; we will only use the top six
    rolls = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    for i in range(0, number):
        roll=int(random.randint(1,6))
        rolls[roll] += 1
    return rolls

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = rollDie(1000)
    print(result[1:])  # print only the indices from 1 to 6
```

And, this is a little bit tricky, but here is a better way to create a list of 7 entries all set to zero:

```
rolls = [0] * 7
```

Why count the zeros yourself?  It's easier to just make Python do the work for you.  :-)

EDIT: The list is length 7 because we want to use indices 1 through 6.  There is also a position 0 in the list, but we don't use it.

Another way to do it is to map the dice rolls onto indices.  It's a pretty simple mapping: just subtract 1.  So, a die roll of 1 would go into index 0 of the list, a die roll of 2 would go into index 1, and so on.  Now we will use every position in the list.

Here's that version:

```
import random

def rollDie(number):
    rolls = [0] * 6
    for i in range(0, number):
        roll=int(random.randint(1,6))
        rolls[roll - 1] += 1
    return rolls

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = rollDie(1000)
    print(result)
```

Comment: Why 7 when it's a six-sided die?

Comment: Because the random numbers are from 1 to 6, but list indices start from 0.  I could also have made the list be 6 long, but then subtracted 1 from each roll.  Hmm, I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Yeah sorry, looking back at it my comment was quite the nitpick, I'll slink away and blame it on lack of sleep...

Answer (score -1):

You should do `random.randint(1, 7)`, otherwise you will never get a 6.

```
...
roll = random.randint(1, 7)
```

Comment: No, `randint()` is *inclusive*. You are thinking of `randrange()`.

Comment: No, it's not inclusive.
The `randint` docstring says:
*Return random integers from `low` (inclusive) to `high` (exclusive).*

Comment: See http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint, `Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b`.

Comment: What version of python are you on? I don't see that in the docstring on Python 2.7, where the string is `Return random integer in range [a, b], including both end points.`.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: You're right. I was using IPython which has a totally different behaviour. :)

Comment: IPython on 2.7 shows the same docstring; a little puzzled where you found that docstring exactly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: that's the `numpy.random.randint` doc.  Maybe user278064 is in `pylab` mode or otherwise did a star import from `numpy`.

Answer (score -3):

```
import random

def dice():

    print random.randint(1,6)

dice()
```

Comment: Your answer would be better received if you explained what was wrong with what the OP had and why your answer is better than the rest that are here.