# How to use the random.choice function with a large amount of numbers

Tags: python, random

I have a homework problem that states use the random.choice function to simulate the 
roll of the die. . It will still simulate rolling a six-sided die 1000 times. Do i have to type out the list like 0, 1000? Or is there an easier way of doing it.

```
 import random
def rolldie3():
#6 variables set to 0 as the counter
one = 0
two = 0
three = 0
four = 0
five = 0
six = 0
#use for loop for 1000 times to run
for i in range(1000):
    scores = range(0,1000)
    #get a random number out of the list
    roll = random.choice(scores)
    if roll == 1:
        one = one + 1
    elif roll == 2:
        two = two + 1
    elif roll == 3:
        three = three + 1
    elif roll == 4:
        four = four + 1
    elif roll == 5:
        five = five + 1
    elif roll == 6:
        six = six + 1
        #return the variables as a list
return [one,two,three,four,five,six]
```

Comment: `for i in xrange(1000):`

Comment: Looks like you are not the only one asking about this today: [Python dice rolling simulation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19188546)

Comment: but im trying to use random.choice instead..

Comment: This is unrelated to your question about `random.choice`, but I'd strongly suggest you use a list (or maybe a dictionary) to hold your counts, rather than using six variables. This will make your counting code much easier: `counts = [0]*6; for _ in range(1000): counts[random.choice(range(6))] += 1` One line for counting is much nicer than your big nested `if`/`elif` block!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
roll = random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

As is, you're choosing a random dice roll, but only doing anything if it's 1 through 6.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the random.choice description: http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice

> random.choice(seq)
>   Return a random element from the non-empty sequence seq. If seq is empty, raises IndexError.

So you need to call this function by passing it a sequence to pick from, which you're trying to do with your scores variable. But that goes from 0 to 999, when you want it to go from 1 to 6. So define your range better:

```
scores = range(1,7)
for i in range(1000):
    #get a random number out of the list
    roll = random.choice(scores)
    ...
```

range(x,y) counts from x (inclusive) to y (exclusive), which is why 7 gives what you want.